# `Permission denied (publickey)` after modifying the users on my server

Tags: ssh, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

It used to work correctly with the same public/private keys and with the same SSH config. I verified this by restoring a backup on my laptop of the `.ssh` folder.

The server is hosted on OCI (Oracle). Last time I used the server, I added and then deleted a new user (along with their home directory). The only thing I did with the main user is add them to a group with the new user which I removed afterwards. I also ran some `chmod` and `chown` commands on the main user's home directory because I was unsuccessfully trying to give the new user the permission to create directories.

Anyway, the reason that I mention this is that I heard that modifying the permissions of certain files can lead to the `Permission denied (publickey)` error.
I know that I'm connecting with the right username and that `authorized_keys` on the server has the right content (because that hasn't changed).

Is there anything I can do to restore my access other than recreate the instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't ssh your instance, you can troubleshoot your instances using Instance Console Connections to restore authorized_keys permission and ownership. As you described your situation, also check your /home permissions.
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/References/serialconsole.htm

Another way is to mount your block volume in a second instance to correct your issue and use back your instance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by restoring a backup of my boot volume and creating a new instance from it. I created the new instance with the same SSH public key and it worked exactly the same as the old one. The reason that this worked is that I had a backup from before I made those changes to the home directory permissions.